# In .net what is the value of "o" and why?

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET  what is the value of "o" and why?

```
object o = 3/2;
```

My thinking is that the default type of object is the lowest type that the value will fit,   so the least / lowest / smallest object that the answer will fit into is a **int32**, then that is what is setup as the base class.

Does that seem right?

Comment: Run the code and find out.  There's no need to hypothesize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"By Default" you are dividing two int32's since that's how the constants are evaluated. The result is the int32 1.

'o' then becomes a 'boxed int32' representing 1.

Comment: i can only flag one as the answer, special thanks to Nicholas Carey for a correct answer as well.

Answer (score 9):

That is called *integer division*. See [/ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx):

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

Also C# Specification [7.7.2 Division operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

Integer division:

> The division rounds the result towards zero, and the absolute value of
>   the result is the largest possible integer that is less than the
>   absolute value of the quotient of the two operands. The result is zero
>   or positive when the two operands have the same sign and zero or
>   negative when the two operands have opposite signs.

So, rounding result towards zero gives `1` for `3/2`. If you want to get floating point number, then you should use *floating-point* division (i.e. at least one of operands should be floating-point value):

```
object o = 3F/2; // 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler sees the constant (invariant) expression `3/2` and performs *constant folding*: the constant expression is evaluated during compilation and the result used to replace the constant expression. Your original statement is changed by the compiler from

```
object o = 3/2 ;
```

to:

```
object o = 1 ;
```

And since you're upcasting the integer `1` to `object` from `struct`, it gets boxed.

One should note that the same happens for other types of constant expressions:

```
string s = "a" + "b" + "c" ;
```

has that same constant folding trasform applied and becomes:

```
string s = "abc" ;
```